# How can I get all checked checkboxes text and store in TestShortName?

Tags: jquery

How can I get all checked checkboxes text and store in TestShortName? For example I need to store 10 Panel and TCA if they are checked and store in TestShortName variable.

```
<div id="cf_2684376_div">
        <div style="overflow:hidden">
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_0">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="10 Panel (AMP,COC,OPI,PCP,THC,?)" id="cf_2684376_0" name="cf_2684376" checked="" title="" onclick="StoreNames()">10 Panel<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_1">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="5 Panel (AMP,COC,OPI,PCP,THC)" id="cf_2684376_1" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()">5 Panel<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_2">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="7 Panel (AMP,COC,OPI,PCP,THC,?)" id="cf_2684376_2" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">7 Panel<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow:hidden">
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_3">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="Amphetamine" id="cf_2684376_3" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">AMP<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_4">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="Barbiturate" id="cf_2684376_4" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">BAR<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_5">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="Breath Alcohol Test" id="cf_2684376_5" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">BAT<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow:hidden">
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_18">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="Phencyclidine" id="cf_2684376_18" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">PCP<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_19">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="Propoxyphene" id="cf_2684376_19" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">PPX<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:33%;float:left;padding:0px" for="cf_2684376_20">
                <input type="CheckBox" value="Tricyclic antidepressant" id="cf_2684376_20" name="cf_2684376" title="" onclick="StoreNames()" disabled="">TCA<input type="hidden" value="Z1h8dUNLU1l5dkFgB1kxR0t@Rn9fcnl3DFNXawMHOAIDBgI~" name="sec_cf_2684376">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Code:

```
function StoreNames(){  
var TestShortName = '';     
$(':checkbox[id^=cf_2684376]:checked').each(function(){                 
    TestShortName != '' ? TestShortName += $(this).next().text() + ';' : TestShortName = $(this).next().text() + ';';       
});         
$('#cf_2684387').val(TestShortName);
```

}

Comment: What do you consider 'text' for a void element such as an input? The text of the associated label?

Comment: Yes the text of the associated label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the text of the label elements associated with the input:

```
function StoreNames() {
     var shortNames = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
         return $(this).parent().text();
     }).get(),
         shortNamesString = shortNames.join(', ') + '.';

     $('#cf_2684387').val( shortNamesString );
}

// call the function with:
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', StoreNames);
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: IT works. Thank you very much. I just had to change last line in the function from text to val

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)